# Correct settings for RosAnswers email?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been getting way too much email from RosAnswers lately, and I'm not sure why.

Here are my settings:

- Asked by me: Instantly
- Answered by me: Instantly
- Individually selected: daily
- Entire forum (tag filtered): Instantly
- Comments and posts mentioning me: Daily
- Email tag filter: Allow only selected tags

And my tag settings....

- Interesting tags: urdf robot_model arm_kinematics
- No ignored tags

Yet I'm still getting emails about threads that I have not voted/commented on, and do not match my tags.

- Re: "problems installing libdc1394v2"
- Re: "What packages provide visual odometry?"
- And plenty more

My only thought is that possibly any post with the substring LU matches (incLUde, vaLUes), but that doesn't work in all cases.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9270/correct-settings-for-rosanswers-email?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) on 2011-03-10**:
Please upgrade now - hopefully the problem is fixed. Please let me know how it goes. Thanks.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-03**:
I've posted an question upstream at http://askbot.org/en/question/330/incorrect-email-filtering

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-03-03**:
Instantly.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-03**:
Are you getting the unwanted emails batched daily or instantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have upgraded to version 0.6.74 and I think that the emails should be fixed.  Please let me know if there's any more problems.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0